# Rails: how to display image from upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave

I'm trying to follow along with Ryan Bates CarrierWave Rails Cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads, but some things have appeared to change since he made it.

Ryan installs carrier wave on the Painting class

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_id, :name, :image
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

and then to display the image he does this

```
<%= image_tag painting.image_url%>
```

I assume that CarrierWave provides the `painting` method.  I installed Carrier Wave on the User class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :email, :image
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

When I tried to do this

```
 <%= image_tag user.image_url %>
```

I got an `"undefined local variable or method for 'user'"` error message

When I tried this

```
<%= image_tag User.image_url %>
```

I got `undefined method`image_url' for # Class:0x0000010248e560>`

This latter error message surprised me, because when I did `rake routes` it showed me this url

```
image GET    /images/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images"}
```

This is the file path to the uploaded image

```
/uploads/user/image/3/cadman.png
```

but I can't figure out how to display it using a Rails method (i.e. not just img src)

Comment: did you make your user variable a new user object? I know that seems obvious, but you never know.

Comment: Rails scaffolding does it in the new method   @user = User.new

Comment: Of course, just checking that you made that step.

Comment: no prob, just so that I can continue on, do you at least know how I could display an image at this file path: /uploads/user/image/3/cadman.png

Comment: You could just write the image tag <img src="uploads/user/image/3/cadman.png">Image</img>

Comment: yeah, sorry, I knew that, I meant using the rails way with image_tag

Comment: Suppose you tried `<%= image_tag @user.image_url%>`?

Comment: @MarkGuk Please submit that as an answer so Michael can accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use instance variable `@user` instead of local variable (that is undefined):

```
<%= image_tag @user.image_url%>
```